# Copying values from one numpy matrix to another dependent on boolean mask

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, replace

As a simple example, I've got the following:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.matrix([[0.34, 0.44, 0.21, 0.51]])
a_max = np.matrix([[0.35, 0.40, 0.20, 0.50]])
```

I would like to apply a transformation where anything in a, that is greater than a_max, is capped at a_max.  I have tried to do this via:

```
a[a>a_max] = a_max[a>a_max]
```

however this throws an error:

```
ValueError: array is not broadcastable to correct shape
```

What is the proper way to do this?  Ignore the fact that I am doing a simple maximum (I am guessing bumpy may have builtin tools to do that particular problem).  My real problem uses a much more complicated set of booleans to create a boolean mask, which then should replace values from a replacement matrix.

Comment: Are you wedded to working with matrices, or will arrays suffice?  (Remember that you can always convert back, if you insist.)

Comment: I would prefer matrices, as I am doing quite a bit of matrix math/linear algebra on the resulting matrix.  I suppose I could convert after assembly though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Life's much easier if you work with arrays and not matrices; it Just Works (tm).

```
>>> a = np.array([[0.34, 0.44, 0.21, 0.51]])
>>> a_max = np.array([[0.35, 0.40, 0.20, 0.50]])
>>> a[a > a_max] = a_max[a > a_max]
>>> a
array([[ 0.34,  0.4 ,  0.2 ,  0.5 ]])
```

I guess you could use `np.where`, though:

```
>>> a = np.matrix([[0.34, 0.44, 0.21, 0.51]])
>>> a_max = np.matrix([[0.35, 0.40, 0.20, 0.50]])
>>> np.where(a > a_max, a_max, a)
matrix([[ 0.34,  0.4 ,  0.2 ,  0.5 ]])
>>>
```

Comment: +1 for `np.where` ... still not sure OP's error gets thrown though. Weird rules of matrix broadcasting?

Comment: The error I get in trunk numpy explains it a little better: "TypeError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment requires a 0 or 1-dimensional input, input has 2 dimensions".  The matrix type fights having its dimension changed pretty hard.

Answer (score 0):

The `minimum` function seems to suffice:

```
a = np.matrix([[999, 0.1, 0.1, 999]])
a_max = np.matrix([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
a_capped = np.minimum(a, a_max)

print repr(a_capped)  # the printed result of matrix.__str__ is weird to me
```

Prints:

```
matrix([[1. , 0.1, 0.1, 4. ]])
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html

Comment: See the last part of my comment: Ignore the fact that I am doing a simple maximum (I am guessing numpy may have builtin tools to do that particular problem). My real problem uses a much more complicated set of booleans to create a boolean mask, which then should replace values from a replacement matrix.  In other words- it is not just taking a min or max.  I have a masking boolean matrix constructed elsewhere (that has nothing to do with a simple cap) that I need to use to determine which values from the replacement matrix come through.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean...my bad. I'll have to think a little harder, obviously...