# OpenCV - Apply color mask to color image

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to apply a color mask to a color image. The color mask is an outline that I want to apply to the color image. The mask is all black except for the outline which is pink ( BGR = `[180, 105,255]`). Oddly, I am able to apply an outline that is cyan `[227,230,49]` using the following method:

Let the color image be `imgColor` and the cyan outline be `maskCyan`. Again, this mask is all black `[0,0,0]` except for the pixels that are part of the outline which are `[227,230,49]`. Then I can apply this over the image by just doing `imgColor_with_cyan_outline = cv2.bitwise_or(imgColor, maskCyan)`. When I do this same this with `maskPink` which has pink pixels instead of cyan using `imgColor_with_pink_outline = cv2.bitwise_or(imgColor, maskPink)` then I am returned the original image without any mask or outline applied to it. I think I'm just misunderstanding how `cv2.bitwise_or()` works, but I'm not sure.

Is there any other way to apply a color mask to a color image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying values from one numpy matrix to another dependent on boolean mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255368/copying-values-from-one-numpy-matrix-to-another-dependent-on-boolean-mask)

Comment: bitwise or -> takes each bit and do OR with the same bit in the other image. for instance if you pixel 63 in one image and 255 in the other one it will result in 255. If you have 63 and 72, will give 127 (63 is 00111111 adn 72 is 01001000 in binary). You can do and with the inverse of the mask as binary (white and black) to "remove" the pixel, or turn them black from the image. Then add it with the cyan one and you get the cyan one in the image, or use numpy to substitute as @DanMašek link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the properties of bitwise `OR` operation. The `cv2.bitwise_or` takes two source images plus an optional mask.

```
cv2.bitwise_or(src1, src2, dst, mask)
```

So if `src1` has a pixel with value 1 and `src2` has a pixel with value 2, then `src1 | src2` is:

```
0001 = src1
0010 = src2
0011 = src1 | src2
```

which makes the resultant pixel value 3. For 8-bit unsigned char images, the maximum resultant pixel value will be 255 (135 | 235 is 255).

Comment: That makes more sense. I thought it meant that it would take the second value if it wasn't 0. So if you had `cv2.bitwise_or([255,255,255],[0,0,0]) = [255,255,255]` and `cv2.bitwise_or([255,255,255],[126,122,0]) = [126,122,0]`. That's what I really need is some function that will replace any pixels in the first image with non-zero pixels from the second argument.

Comment: @greenthumbtack What you want is to copy one image to another based on mask. For that see this excellent post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41572887/equivalent-of-copyto-in-python-opencv-bindings

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cv2.inrange` function for masking if you have a baundary for filtering. Modify following code as your values. Check for syntax  according to your opencv version

```
Pink=cv2.inrange(pink baundary)
Black=cv2.inrange(black baundary)
Mask= Pink+Black
```

For more information you can read

> https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html

Comment: How would I use this? The mask has only 2 colors on it, black and pink. I thought `inrange` is for looking for a color in an image, not applying a mask.